Dropdown menu not showing properly in datatable
My datatable has a button and I'm using a dropdown menu of adminLTE. But it's not showing properly if there's only 1 record on the table. What's happening is I have to scroll down the table in order to see the dropdown menu.

The green button above allows to open the dropdown menu, but it's showing like this:

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/AdminLTE/adminlte.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
var table = $('#tableCA').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("RequestTable", "CARequest")',
                    dataSrc: "data"

                },
                "language": {
                    "emptyTable": "No Request Available",
                    "processing": "<div class='text-center'><span class='fa fa-spinner fa-pulse'></span> Loading...</div>"
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        orderable: false,
                        data: "ID",
                        render: function (data, type, row) {                             
                            var editButton = '';
                            var viewButton = '';
                            var detailButton = '';
                            var approveButton = '';
                            if (row.StatusID == 1) {
                                editButton = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary btn-outline js-edit" data-id="' + data + '" title="Edit"><span class="fa fa-pencil-square"></span></a>';

                            }
                            if (row.StatusID != 1) {
                                viewButton = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-outline js-view" data-id="' + data + '" title="View"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span></a>';

                            }
                            if (row.StatusID == 2 || row.StatusID == 3) {
                                // '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-success btn-outline js-approve" data-id="' + data + '" title="Approve"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></a>';
                                approveButton =
                                        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-xs btn-outline btn-success dropdown-toggle asd" data-toggle="dropdown">' +
                                            '<span class="fa fa-check"></span>' +
                                        '</a>' +
                                        '<ul class="dropdown-menu">' +
                                            '<li><a href="#" onclick="approve(4, this)" data-id="' + data + '">Approve</a></li>' +
                                            '<li><a href="#" onclick="approve(3, this)" data-id="' + data + '">For Final Approval</a></li>' +
                                        '</ul>';
                            }
                      
                            var deleteButton = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-outline js-delete" data-id="' + data + '" title="Delete"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>';
                            var detailButton = '<a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-outline js-detail" data-id="' + data + '" title="Breakdown/Detail budget"><span class="fa fa-list"></span></a>'                            
                            return approveButton + ' ' + viewButton + ' ' + detailButton + ' ' + deleteButton + ' ' + editButton;
                        }
                    },
                 
                ],
                order: [1, 'asc'],
                scrollY: '50vh',
                scrollCollapse: true,
                paging: false,
                info: true,
                ordering: true,
                searching: true,
                scrollX: true,
                deferRender: true,
                processing: true
            })

I tried adding z-index on the dropdown menu but it still not working, any help would be appreciated.

Did you check the properties of the elements that hide your dropdown (e.g. z-index, important rule)? Can you share them with us in your question? Moreover, it would be helpful if you could provide a minimal reproducible example.

Have you tried setting the menu's boundary to 'viewport' or 'window'? IIRC, the Bootstrap dropdown menu doesn't work well when nested within a short table.
